# How to ignore case sensitivity and count array values?

Tags: php, arrays

What might be the simplest way to count array values regardless of case sensitivities?

#### Attempt

```
$arr=array("A","B","b","A","b", "a", "A");
print_r(array_count_values($arr));
```

or:

```
$arr=array("AliCE","Alice","bob","AlICE","BOB", "aLIce", "alice");
print_r(array_count_values($arr));
```

#### [Demo](https://3v4l.org/g16YV)

#### Current Output

```
Array
(
    [A] => 3
    [B] => 1
    [b] => 2
    [a] => 1
)
```

#### Desire Output

```
Array
(
    [A] => 4
    [B] => 2
)
```

Or:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 4
    [b] => 2
)
```

Comment: [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map)/[`strtoupper`](http://php.net/strtoupper) beforehand.

Comment: Covered within https://stackoverflow.com/q/28657236/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `array_map` but as an alternate, join into a string, change case, split into an array:

```
print_r(array_count_values(str_split(strtolower(implode($arr)))));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can map the letters to uppercase first using `strtoupper`:

```
$arr = array("A","B","b","A","b", "a", "A");
print_r(array_count_values(array_map('strtoupper', $arr)));
```

**Output:**

```
(
    [A] => 4
    [B] => 3
)
```

Comment: I didn't see mario's comment until after I came back to the question. I had opened a PHP console in another tab.

Comment: @JedLynch I feel ya happened today to me for a couple of python questions by like literally seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` with `array_key_exists` and `strtoupper`

```
$arr=array("A","B","b","A","b", "a", "A");
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    array_key_exists(strtoupper($v), $res) ? ($res[strtoupper($v)]++) : ($res[strtoupper($v)] = 1); 
}
print_r($res);
```

[Working Example](https://3v4l.org/0hGgr)